# why put $ with $self and $body? And is self the same as $self

Tags: jquery, syntax

I'm learning jQuery by trying to understand other people's code.  I ran into this:

```
jQuery.fn.myFunc = function(options, callback) {

//stuff

  jQuery(this)[settings.event](function(e) {
    var self = this,
    $self = jQuery( this ),
    $body = jQuery( "body" );
     //etc.
  }

//more stuff

}
```

My understanding is that `$` refers to the jQuery object.  So why put `$` with `$self` and `$body`? And is `self` the same as `$self`?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

**$self** has little to do with **$**, which is an alias for jQuery in this case. Some people prefer to put a dollar sign together with the variable to make a distinction between regular vars and jQuery objects.

example:

```
var self = 'some string';
var $self = 'another string';
```

These are declared as two different variables. It's like putting underscore before private variables.

A somewhat popular pattern is:

```
var foo = 'some string';
var $foo = $('.foo');
```

That way, you know $foo is a cached jQuery object later on in the code.

Comment: Very clear. I appreciate you explaining why someone might use the $var convention.

Comment: How do you deal with variable beginning with a $ for jquery variable and jslint?

Answer (score 30):

This is pure JavaScript.

There is nothing special about `$`. It is just a character that may be used in variable names.

```
var $ = 1;
var $$ = 2;
alert($ + $$);
```

jQuery just assigns it's core function to a variable called `$`. The code you have assigns `this` to a local variable called `self` and the results of calling jQuery with `this` as an argument to a global variable called `$self`.

It's ugly, dirty, confusing, but `$`, `self` and `$self` are all different variables that happen to have similar names.

Comment: Tastes vary, but I don't find it ugly at all. The dollar sign has been used to denote $STRINGS and other special variables for a long time. Definitely going to adopt this convention.

Answer (score 9):

No, it certainly is not. It is just another variable name. The `$()` you're talking about is actually the [jQuery core function](http://docs.jquery.com/Core). The `$self` is just a variable. You can even rename it to `foo` if you want, this doesn't change things. The `$` (and `_`) are legal characters in a Javascript identifier.

Why this is done so is often just some code convention or to avoid clashes with reversed keywords. I often use it for `$this` as follows:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Answer (score 7):

self and $self aren't the same. The former is the object pointed to by "this" and the latter a jQuery object whose "scope" is the object pointed to by "this". Similarly, $body isn't the body DOM element but the jQuery object whose scope is the body element.

Answer (score 2):

The dollarsign as a prefix in the var name is a usage from the concept of the [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).