# What is the official correct way to declare jQuery variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn jQuery. I keep seeing people using different methods of declaring variables.

I have seen `var variable;`, `var $variable;`, and `$variable;`. Which one (if any of these) is the official correct way to declare jQuery variables.

Comment: You should prefix them with `$resigDoYouRegretIt_` /irony

Comment: See [jquery variable syntax
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916584/jquery-variable-syntax).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should always declare a variable with `var` (whatever the scope, unless creating it on an object), *implied* globals are bad, don't do it.

As for `variable` vs. `$variable`, there is no official stance, just have a convention that you and your team stick to.

As a general rule *some* follow, (I don't follow this, some do), use `variable` for variables that aren't jQuery objects and `$variable` for variables that are, those who use this typically find that seeing `$something` and knowing immediately it's a jQuery object to be handy.

Answer (score 4):

Use `var` to define variables to ensure that they are scoped properly, usually locally within a function.  My convention is to use `$variable` when the variable holds a jQuery object (result of a selector) and `variable` for everything else.

BTW -- they aren't *jquery* variables, but rather *javascript* variables.  JQuery is just another (albeit the most popular at present) javascript framework, not a language in and of itself.

Comment: what is this javascript you speak of? does it run on jQuery, is it a plugin?

Answer (score 3):

There is no official correct way to declare variables for jQuery..

They are all javascript variables, [and these are the rules for javascript variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Variables)

Using the `$` at the beginning is a convention that the variable is holding a jQuery object (*since the jquery uses the $ sign for the function wrapper*)

The diffeernce of using `var` or not, is in the scope of the variable. Using `var` declares it local, not using `var` adds it to the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Nick already explained why you should use `var`.

The reason behind `variable` and `$variable` is that `$` is associated with jQuery and should imply that this variable holds a jQuery object. To avoid unnecessary function calls to jQuery like `$(variable)` where `variable` actually already holds a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "jQuery variable", they are Javascript variables. When learning jQuery you have to learn some Javascript, as jQuery is just a library for Javascript.

You declare a variable using the `var` keyword. You can also use a variable without declaring it, and it will implicitly be declared as a global variable, but that is not recommended. You should declare variables in the scope where they are used.

Sometimes putting a $ sign as the first character of a variable name is used to indicate that it's intended for containing a reference to a jQuery object, however there is no official recommendation, and the language itself doesn't care what you name your variables.

Answer (score -2):

The ones with `var` are local variables, the one without it is global.  So it's not just a matter of style.  Apart from that use anything you like, personally I haven't seen "$" prefixed variables, but maybe they are useful if you mix a lot of jQuery and standard JavaScript code.

Comment: -1 declaring vars in global scope creates global variables as well, so the var keyword isn't synonym to local variables.