# why type $this = $(this) in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and have noticed someone go:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Why do this? Is it to save typing? Does it help performance? Is it fairly standard practice?

Also I've started doing things such as:

```
var minus_button = $('#minus_button');
```

Should this instead be `var $minus_button = $('#minus_button');` to signal it's a jquery object?

I read http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines but couldn't find any suggestions.

Comment: Also from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916584/jquery-variable-syntax I noticed someone uses $self ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's a naming convention to signal that that variable is a jquery `object` reference. That way it is very obvious whether or not you can use a jquery `function` on the `object` *or* if the `object` needs to be converted into a jquery `object` to apply said `function`.

Example:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myelement');
var $element = $('#myelement');

// not a jquery object
console.log($(element).val());
// jquery object
console.log($element.val());
```

Comment: weird, i would have thought $(document.getElementById('z')) would be exactly the same as $('#z')

Comment: Well it is, they both return a jquery object. My example is a little different than that.

Comment: don't you essentially compare $(element) to $element in your example?

Comment: I am showing you that in order to use a jquery function you need to have a reference to jquery object first. So I do getElementId which returns me a DOM element. With the naming convention in question, i don't prefix the variable name with a $. So when I want to apply a jquery function later, I have to convert it into a jquery object. I was merely showing how the $ makes it more readable and when I went to apply a jquery function, I knew the `element` object was not a jquery object by the name of the object alone.

Comment: Also it caches the element so you don't have to repeatedly go through the dom to find it.  So if you have to repeatedly get an element it improve's performance

Answer (score 1):

It's just a form of [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Disadvantages).