# $ at the beginning and at the end of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why would a JavaScript variable start with a dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign)

I realized some syntax with jquery and didnt know what it is. here goes:

```
var $foo = $("bar").blah();

var hello$ = $("stgelse").etc();
```

What is the difference between these? and why are they like that?

Also, For example:

```
var $foo = $("").blah();
```

var should already contain whatever right side is returning ? no?

Can you please elaborate?

Comment: It's just a convention so you can tell at a glance that the variable is a jQuery object. There's nothing special about that syntax since `$` is a valid character.

Comment: so there is no magic? cool why dont u put that as answer. thanks.

Comment: this link can be useful :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916584/jquery-variable-syntax

Comment: `$` can be used in the middle as well, e.g. `var holy$hit = intensify($hit);`

Comment: can also be used by itself e.g. `var $;` or `var $$;`

Comment: I have also seen it used to indicate observables e.g. `abc$: Observable<boolean>;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var $foo = $("bar").blah();
```

- `var` is a keyword that makes the variable local in certain cases. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)
- `$foo` is the name of this variable. There is no need for the `$`, and indeed it confuses everything, but some languages (like PHP) need them to say "this is a variable". It could've been just `foo`
- `=` is the assignment to make `$foo` have whatever comes from the right hand side
- `$` is another variable, but a special one: this is your JQuery thingy! From there you see it does all the JQuery stuff, like "find `bar`, do `blah()` etc.

The same basically goes for the other line, but in this case someone thought that `hello$` would be a nice name for a var :)

Comment: +1 ---but 3 point loled me .... op is 6k rep user

Comment: But now it's an ultra=cannonical answer :)

Comment: @NullPointer rep doesnt mean anything (sometimes). i wrok at Y! but never used javascript really. just copy paste so i was reading some stuff about it. js is cryptic:)

Comment: @DarthVader if are new try http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript-combined  i loveed that

Answer (score 7):

In Javascript you can use `$` in a variable name (or as a variable name all by itself, like it's used by the jQuery library for example), there is no special meaning in the language itself.

Some people use `$` at the beginning of a variable name to indicate that the variable should contain a jQuery object, for example:

```
var $form = $('form');
```

A `$` at the end of variable names was used in BASIC for string variables, which might be one reason for using it to mean something when naming variables in other languages also. Example:

```
10 LET NAME$="JOHN DOE"
20 PRINT NAME$
```

Answer (score 2):

here

```
var hello$ and $foo
```

`hello$` , $foo are just a [variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916584/jquery-variable-syntax)

and  `$("").blah();`

`$` is jquery object

<sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Answer (score 1):

`$` is just a name - names in JavaScript can contain dollar signs, and can consist of just a dollar sign.

Its like  just normal javascript variable but as per convention is used to identify jquery objects variable from normal javascript variable. there nothing special about it.