# Variables naming convention in Javascript & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

From what i understand, JavaScript requires variable to be defined using `var` keyword, and jQuery allows to define variables using `$` symbol, I am wondering what added benefits does it bring when i define variable using jQuery, or is it purely preference? why will i use one convention over the other?

Also, what is the difference between the following variable declarations?

- `var foo`
- `var $oo`
- `$foo`

Comment: _“JavaScript requires variable to be defined using var keyword”_ – no, not necessarily. But without the `var` keyword they will always be global, not matter where that initialization occurs. And the $ part does not “define” a variable in itself, it is just part of the variable _name_.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916584/jquery-variable-syntax

Comment: Don't use `$` in variable names. It's hideous. I know it's *somewhat* of a convention for jQuery users but it's a terrible one. There's just no need. You should have sensible enough names that you don't need a `$` to know it's a jQuery object.

Comment: > JavaScript requires variable to be defined using var keyword, and jQuery allows to define variables using $ symbol

this is wrong. JQuery is a (big) JavaScript framework, not a JavaScript "addon", you can't define a variable in JQuery, you just access to JQuery using $() - not $name
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dollar sign is not a variable definition. It is short for jQuery. More exactly $ === jQuery. **Edit**: This is in general, not in variable definition (as CBroe specified in comment).

So the fact that some use it for variable declaration is purely preference, and in my opinion a misguiding one. Or maybe they have php background and are used to the $varName definition from there.

About the differences, you have difference between:

```
var foo
```

and

```
foo
```

The first one is a local definition, while the second is global.

Example:

```
  function test() {
      var a = 2;
      b = 5;
  }

  test();
  console.log(a); // undefined
  console.log(b); // 5
```

Comment: _“It is short for jQuery”_ – no, in `$foo` it is simply part of the variable name. (In `$(…)` it references the jQuery object, yes.)

Comment: That's what I meant, read the following line. "So the fact that some use it for variable declaration is purely preference, and in my opinion a misguiding one". Maybe I should rephrase that?

Comment: Since OP used `$foo` as example, it might be misunderstood … but lets not nitpick, I just wanted to be clear about it. As for using it in variable names, which you consider “misguiding”, I think it makes sense when it is used to signify that a variable actually holds a jQuery object. `var $elements = $('.selector')`

Answer (score 5):

It is common to use a $ in front of the variable name when the variable is a jQuery object. Say for instance `var $body = jQuery('body');` is a way to let other developers reading the code(and your future self) know they are dealing with a jQuery object instead of the body element directly. Definitely a preference thing, I would say decide what works best for your team and stick with it!