# How to use mousemove to change a div's background color?

Tags: jquery, css

I was hoping to import the mouse coordinates to the numbers in a div's change background color to rgb(event.clientx, eventclientY, 50).  Any ideas?

```
  <body>

  <p>
  <span>Move the mouse over the div.</span>
  <span>&nbsp;</span>
   </p>
  <div></div>

   <script>
   $( "div" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
      var $corX = $("(event.pageX)/10");
      var $corY = $("(event.pageY)");
      var $coloChange = $("rgb(" + $corx+ ", " + $corY + ",40)");
      $("div").css"("background", "$colorChange");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$("div").css"("background", $colorChange);`

Comment: I believe this is what you need:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234256/find-mouse-position-relative-to-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, you almost was right in your code. A 'variable' on jquery does not need necessarily the $, you can see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916584/jquery-variable-syntax)). :)  and you can see [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.pagex/) how to use .pageX and .pageY, that is  simple as well.

Here is you code, just a little different, now working.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/on27dn0c/

P.S. You can use transition on CSS for a better effect.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Hi Claudio, this is perfect, exactly what I was looking for.  I tried recreating your fiddle, even copied and pasted your code into a new fiddle and it didn't work. Do I have to set it up differently that the default

Comment: Hi, You're on the right way, but you just forgot one thing. Jquery is a **Library Javascript**, so it's not default on the browsers, and on the _Fiddle_ isn't different  :)  On your _Fiddle_ click on the buttom "External Resources" (left at screen) and add the link of the **Library Jquery** (Using CDN). You can find the links of all versions [here](https://code.jquery.com/). If you want it right now, here is the link -> https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js  :)

Comment: If there is no more doubts, don't forget to choose this answer as the right ✔ to close the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you're putting mathematical calculations in to strings, and those strings in to jQuery objects. You just need to execute them directly. The same for the concatenation of the `rgb()` string. You also have mis-matched cases in your variable names. Once you fix those issues your code should work:

```js
$("div").mousemove(function(e) {
    var corX = e.pageX / 10;
    var corY = e.pageY;
    $("div").css("background-color", "rgb(" + corX + ", " + corY + ",40)");
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <span>Move the mouse over the div.</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<div></div>
```

Comment: But `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` are the coordinates on the page and Mike probably wants the color to vary between 0 and 255 on each channel. In which case you'd need to compensate for element width and element position on the page.

Comment: Possible, although the OP doesn't state that at all. `offsetX` and `offsetY` would be more applicable in that case as you can simply compare them to the height/width of the element